# Want a checkbox to be selected according to its database value only in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I have 12 check boxes and i want to be checked or unchecked these check boxes according to there database values. I want to perform this action in c# not in ASP .NET.

Comment: you have a value from DB like (0, 1) or (true, false) right? so why dont you set this value to your cell value? tons of examples on internet.

Comment: could not get a single one example

Comment: yes i have 0 and 1 in database

Answer (score 1):

You can convert 0 or 1 to boolean using `Convert.ToBoolean()` method:

```
checkBox1.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(1); //true -- any number except for 0
checkBox1.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(0); //false
```